# pybloomfiltermmap ： str() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: python, bloom-filter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLGnF.png)

I follow here https://github.com/axiak/pybloomfiltermmap to install pybloomfilter and first I got the setuptools error. I installed setuptools and can be imported from python. Then I done `sudo python setup.py install` under dir of pybloomfilter, I got the errors showed in the picture.

Anyone can help? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded this :https://github.com/fragglet/c-algorithms/releases

and install it.
and then make the dynamic connection through the following way:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/where/you/install/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  sudo ldconfig

then, it works.